# android master-detail template. how to pass the master data to the detail without static

Tags: android, master-detail

In the android there is a master detail template, to demonstrate the use of fragments.

in

> TakalaDetailFragment

there is a comment saying:

```
// Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
// arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
// to load content from a content provider.
```

I cannot find a way to pass the data from the master to the detail, to pass the "key" info for the detail to generate the GUI.

Could you please suggest a place (in a function) that pass the data from the master to the detail.

I have no idea what is a loader, and im not working with a database so I don't need a courser, the data is an XML file.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find a way to pass the data from the master to the detail, to pass the "key" info for the detail to generate the GUI.

You can use interface to communicate with fragments, define an interface in your master fragment and implement it in your activity then update your detail fragment from there.

Read this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_activitycommunication).

and the [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

This is the best example, there are two fragments headlinesfragment and articlefragment with dynamic UI, follow how they have interface on articlefragment to let which headline is picked. Follow the tutorial properly. You should understand it well.